# Feign Ribbon client wait and retry

Tags: netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign, netflix-ribbon, feign

I am using Feign Ribbon client to talk to a service.
I have a client that fails immediately after configured maxAutoRetries in ribbon. Is there a property in feign or ribbon like "wait and retry" which can wait for configured time and retry.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `Retryer` Bean for this purpose.

```java
@Configuration
public class RetryConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Retryer retryer() {
        // default retryer will retry 5 times waiting waiting
        // 100 ms per retry with a 1.5* back off multiplier
        return Retryer.Default();
    }
}
```

You can create your own `Retryer` implementation if your needs are different from the default.

Once defined, this retry configuration will be used when a `RetryableException` is thrown during any `Feign` calls.  You may need to also register an `ErrorDecoder` to ensure that the response from your endpoint is wrapped appropriately:

```java
public class MyErrorDecoder implements ErrorDecoder {
    @Override
    public Exception decode(String methodKey, Response response) {
       // handle the error, wrap and return
       return new RetryableException(exception);
    }
}

@Bean
public ErrorDecoder errorDecoder() {
    return new MyErrorDecoder();
}
```

Comment: The retrier bean should return new Retryer.Default();